# Cannot build a class called statically in PHP

Tags: php

I have this structure:

```
class MyCollection extends BaseCollection
{

    public function getEntityCLass() : string
    {
        return Item::class;
    }

}
```

The base collection looks like this:

```
abstract class BaseCollection {
   public function __construct(array $elements = array())
    {
        foreach ($elements as $entity) {
            $this->add($entity);
        }
    }
}
```

This makes no sense to me ; getEntityClass should return a string but returns Item::class.

Sending an array to the class works but I honestly don't know why. Anyone care to explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Item::class` is a short way of giving a string for the full class, it isn't a method or an object.

For instance.

Instead of `Big\Massive\Long\Namespaced\ClassOfSomeSort`, so long as you have imported that class with a use statement you can say `ClassOfSomeSort::class` which will give you the long string.